# ASP REST Service - Authentication issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, rest

I have found heaps of material/info on my issue, but nothing I've found seems to fix it.

I have written an ASP REST service, that authenticates with NTLM that takes in a Jpeg as a stream (saving the image to the server), and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

```
namespace Services
{
    [System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
        IgnoreExtensionDataObject = true,
        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
        AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
        public bool Upload(Stream image)
        {
            //code here
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The web.config is as follows:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="500000000"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultWebHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultWebHttpBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00"  openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000">
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000"  maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, accept, authorization, origin, referer, user-agent, x-token"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

on IIS, its running with Windows Authentication only. And its being called from this code:
        var wcfServiceUrl = 'http://server/MyService.svc/Upload/';

```
    function uploadImage(image) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', wcfServiceUrl, true);
        xhr.send(photo);
    }
```

This works if I call it from the server locally (i.e. from a html page on the server). However if I run it from anywhere else (a test.html page locally, a hosted webpage on another server) it fails with the following:

```
OPTIONS http://server/MyService.svc/Upload/ 401 (Unauthorized)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server/MyService.svc/Upload/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

The header is as follows:

```
Remote Address:0.0.0.0
Request URL:http://server/MyService.svc/Upload/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, accept, authorization, origin, referer, user-agent, x-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:1293
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 29 Oct 2015 03:46:52 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate:NTLM
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:server
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Anybody have any ideas? Really stuck here

Comment: Wow.... so much help

Comment: As far as I can tell from the header it _is_ using NTLM security but says you're unauthorised. Are you logged into the same domain with the same user on the remote server that you are using for the local functioning call?

Comment: I suggest you follow this guide to gather more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/07/14/howto-diagnose-iis-401-access-denied.aspx

Comment: Hi Nick,It is using NTLM. I am authorised and logged into the same domain with the same user on the remote server.

Comment: What do the IIS logs say? What is the error subcode? Did you follow the link I posted? It will reveal more information. Its enlightening to compare IIS logs between functioning and non functioning calls. What difference do you see?

Comment: I followed the link - which explains what kind of error a 401.2 is. Completely not helpful.

Comment: Did you know before that it was a 401.2? When you compare the functioning IIS log and non functioning IIS log what do you see?

Comment: So none of that info about 401.2 gives you any clues as to the possible issue? I typed 401.2 and I got this site which suggests some more specific things that it might be. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2008/02/20/401-2-troubleshooting-for-intranet-websites-using-integrated-authentication.aspx

Comment: A lot of that info is about client configuration which is in line with your issue - works on one client but a different one.

Comment: Can't do anything until this is solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512797/vs2013-debugger-gone-awol

Comment: Why do you need to get VS working if you are testing this with "a test.html page locally"?

Comment: I think given that you don't know my full position/situation, you shouldn't be looking for low hanging fruit to criticize me with and stroak you ego.

How about you just help get my VS up and running for now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I'm criticizing you