# VS2013 debugger gone AWOL

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

"Unable to start debugging on the webserver. The process has already been attached"

I've done EVERYTHING from removing/recreating the IIS site, recycling the app pool account, and I've even done a complete reboot.

So from a complete reboot, do nothing but open VS2013, try to run a webservice in debug, and it complains its already attached??? Is there some sort of a flag that could jam up or something

Comment: Can someone help - for the love of god!!! I don't know what to do???

Comment: A restart should fix it, or just find the web server process and kill it.

Comment: If that doesn't work, go through the top 3 google suggestions that come up when you search on that error.

Comment: Its between 8:30pm and 11:30pm in the US (major user base for SO), and this site gets the most hits between 9am and 5pm (working hours), don't be so impatient, if you want tech support like that, call up Microsoft with a credit card, they'll be happy to help, otherwise sit tight and wait for the right person to come along and play along with any obvious questions or ideas other people have.